# The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me I am using this script..

Found the full code [Here](http://pastebin.com/qY1cN1ry)

```
 public void sendemail(int MemberId, DataTable Member, int rowNo)
    {
        MailMessage msgMail = new MailMessage();

        msgMail.To = Member.Rows[rowNo]["EmailID"].ToString();
        msgMail.From = "admin@auditionbollywood.com"; 
        msgMail.Subject = "Auditions BollyWood Account Expire";
        msgMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Hi !\n\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("Your Audition Bollywood Account has been expired.Please pay the payment for activation.\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("Click the below link to pay to activate your account\n");
        string link = string.Format("http://www.auditionbollywood.com/paymentrenewal.aspx?MemberId={0}", MemberId.ToString());
        sb.Append(link);
        sb.AppendFormat("\n\nThank You");
        msgMail.Body = sb.ToString();
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", "mail.auditionbollywood.com");
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", 587);
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", 2);
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "admin@auditionbollywood.com");
        msgMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "**********");
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.auditionbollywood.com";
        SmtpMail.Send(msgMail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbolic name for error code 0x80040217 is `CDO_E_LOGON_FAILURE` which has the following description:

> The transport was unable to log on to the server.

You need to provide valid credentials to send using that SMTP server.

Comment: its not working, i've tried the same conf to setup an outlook,

Comment: @KushalGupta: Looking at your source code on pastebin I do not see any attempt to authenticate against the SMTP server.

Comment: I called that function on line 110

Comment: @KushalGupta: I overlooked that you actually authenticate in your code. The `SmtpMail` class was obsoleted long time ago and replaced by the `SmtpClient` class which I suggest that you use. But no matter how you send the mail you currently is told by the server that you fail to authenticate so you have to fix that. It could be a wrong password or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the SMTP server rejected your e-mail.Reasons:

1. information is incorrect
2. SMTP server does not allow you to send e-mails externally.Check with SMTP administrator.

3.change email login security not to use the 2-step verification, but only a password.

Comment: its not working, i've tried the same conf to setup an outlook,
everything is fine..

Comment: Use smtpclient instead.. I think smtpmail is obsolete..

Comment: tried that too.. :( :(